# После загрузки фотографии на S3 получаю некорректный url при обращении

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Я загружаю фотографии на s3 с помощью Carrierwave. Потом при чтении url он приходит некорректным. На девелопменте нормально приходит, а на продакшене нет. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина?

Вот мои настройки  Carrierwave

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => "#{ENV['ACCESS_KEY']}",
      :aws_secret_access_key  => "#{ENV['SECRET_KEY']}",
      :region                 => "#{ENV['REGION']}"
  }
  config.fog_directory  = "#{ENV['BUCKET']}"
end
```

Вот такой url я получаю на продакшене. Обратите внимание на два слеша подряд.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com//uploads/...
```

А такой получаю на девелопменте(он корректный)

```
https://{bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/...
```

Comment: Ткну наугад в очевидное: одноимённые переменные среды все заданы же?

Comment: D-side уже исправил, пролема в env файле. Он у меня в папке shared был, перенес в корень, но при деплое стирается, как настроить чтобы при деплое он не удалялся?

Comment: Держать в `shared`, делать при каждом деплое симлинк туда. Capistrano ж? Смотрите в конфиги.